# Not including whitespace when detecting text width with `<span>` trick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented a jQuery pluggin to correct the width of `<input/>` elements depending on how much text they have, as shown:

```
$.fn.correctWidth = function () {
    var tempSpan = $('<span>')
        .html(this.val())
        .css('font-size', this.css('font-size'))
       .insertBefore(this);
    this.width(tempSpan.width());
    tempSpan.remove();
    return this;
};
```

The problem is that, sometimes, the `<span>` element's width is much larger than the actual text width.

It seems that this occasional problem is because the detected width includes the whitespace between the end of the text and the end of the line.

How can I make sure that the whitespace is not included? Is there an alternative approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change

```
  this.width(tempSpan.width());
```

To

```
  this.width(tempSpan.innerWidth());
```

Answer (score 2):

You better set also the same font-family(the width of font usually differs).
Furthermore you should use

```
$('<pre style="display:inline;"/>')
```

...instead of the span.
Repeated whitespaces will be ignored in a span, but not in a text-input(and not inside pre)